# Cannot run xampp

Tags: xampp

I am pretty new to ubuntu and i tried to run xampp. Downloaded the file installed it this way

```
chmod +x xampp......run
./xampp.......run
```

The files were installed in `opt/ direktroy ( not`/etc/opt`, don't know is it right this way ) under the name of`lampp/`. After that I tried to run it like:

```
chmod +x manager-linux-x64.run
./manager-linux-x64.run
```

And some error occured in the terminal:

```
toma@toma-hp-zbook-17:/opt/lampp$ sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run 
[1882:1882:0911/232638.612121:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
[1892:1892:0911/232638.644026:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($HOME is /home/toma which is owned by toma.)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: chromium-browser: not found
[1923:1923:0911/232638.697093:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 851: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_for_XAMPP'
```

Also created a desktop shortcut but it obviously won't work again. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `XAMPP` always makes problems und Linux. Have you considered installing a full `lamp`-stack?

Comment: I am not familiar with the lamp-stack. Will read a little about it. As I know it is the Linux equivalent for XAMPP, right ?

Comment: Well, almost. Instead of one application you have all parts (Linux, Apache, MySQL/MariaDB, PHP, PHPMyAdmin) seperate. That, of course, makes the effort to install and maintain a little bit bigger but you are much more independent and if one program is not working as desired you can change that in no time. You can install updates for one application without touching others and you don't have to rely on the XAMPP team to get newer versions. If you have problems with one of the programs the community is able to help much faster.

Comment: I guess I will try with the stack. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this worked for me..
first install it from xampp website.....

All you have to do is stop Mysql and apache2 first

sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

Then Start your

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

```
Switch to the XAMPP installation directory. Type in

cd /opt/lampp

and press ↵ Enter

Enter the "Open" command. Type in

sudo ./manager-linux-x64.run

and press ↵ Enter
```

Enter your password when prompted. Type in the password you usually use to log into your computer, then press ↵ Enter.